# Aggregate columns based on values and sum (GROUPBY)

Tags: python

```
    import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'Area': ['Tipperary','Tipperary','Cork','Dublin'],
                     'Deaths': [11,33,44,55],
                      'Year': [2007,2007,2007,2008]}
)
```

How can I ensure my groupby sums by the common values in Area but keeps the rest of the columns as it is?

[problem on larger scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjyUE.png)

in this picture i have two values for Tipperary for the same year 2007, I would like to go through these summing any values that have the same Area value reducing my row count.

Comment: An aggregate cannot include rows that are not used in group by. If you wish to include the rest of the rows (and you think their values are common as well), include them in the group by. Simply pass a list of field names to groupby to group by multiple fields.

Comment: x = suicide_data1.groupby(by=['Year','Sex','Area','Age Group'], as_index=False)['Suicides'].sum() , thank you that has worked.